# ElasticSearch: pro and cons of having different indices for same mapping definition

Tags: database-design, elasticsearch, architecture

Let's say I define two ElasticSearch mappings such as :

```json
"firstMapping" : {
    "properties" : {
        "name" : {
            "type" : "string"
        },
        "someProperty" : {
            "type" : "string"
        }
    }
}
```

And

```json
"secondMapping" : {
    "properties" : {
        "name" : {
            "type" : "string"
        },
        "someOtherProperty" : {
            "type" : "string"
        }
    }
}
```

I have two questions:

1. **For now, these mappings are created in two differents indices for no obvious reason** (other than rapidly counting the number of documents in one mapping by counting the number of elements in its index, which seems a quite spurious reason).

   I would think the preffered way of doing this, is to create a single index holding those two related mappings, as a relational database would hold many different tables.
2. **For each mapping, one document has an "origin", either "realtime" or "batch".** As you may have guessed already, for each "batch" document there should be exactly one corresponding "realtime" document, each essentially holding the same values.

   To put it differently, in that system, a "record" should be composed of exactly two documents : a "batch" document and a "realtime" document which are otherwise identical.

   Thus, having a single "batch" or "realtime" document should be considered abnormal; hence the need to have a simple way of comparing "batch" and "realtime" data one against each other.

   At the moment, each mapping is actually created in two indices, such that

   - `batchFirstMappingIndex` contains `firstMapping` documents of "batch" origin
   - `realtimeFirstMappingIndex` contains `firstMapping` documents of "realtime" origin

   (resp. secondMapping)

   As mappings are essentially types, I'm wondering whether it would be more appropriate to have a single mapping for both origin, such as:

   ```json
   "firstMappingWithOrigin" : {
       "properties" : {
           "origin" : {
               "type" : "boolean"
           },
           "name" : {
               "type" : "string"
           },
           "someProperty" : {
               "type" : "string"
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   (resp. secondMapping)
   with `false` value for "batch" and `true` value for "realtime"

To sum up with, I currently have 4 resources in 4 separate indices:

- batchFirstMappingIndex/firstMapping
- realtimeFirstMappingIndex/firstMapping
- batchSecondMappingIndex/secondMapping
- realtimeSecondMappingIndex/secondMapping

I think we could easily have only 2 resources in just one index:

- myIndex/firstMappingWithOrigin
- myIndex/secondMappingWithOrigin

**What are the benefits and drawbacks of both solutions ? What are the best justifications for the second approach ?**

For both questions, I'm especially concerned about:

- read (generating aggregates on the fly) and write performance
- index maintenance (adding/removing/modifying mappings properties for instance)
- comparing "batch" and "realtime" data

Comment: I think the following article by the ES folks should shed some light on this: https://www.elastic.co/blog/index-vs-type Also note that "removing properties" is not possible in ES and "modifying properties" is limited to only compatible changes.

Comment: @Val I think you should actually make your comment an answer, I would  definitely accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following article by the ES folks should shed some light on this: http://elastic.co/blog/index-vs-type

Also note that "removing properties" is not possible in ES and ["modifying properties"](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-put-mapping.html#updating-field-mappings) is limited to only compatible changes.